# Diffrent number of rows while running every time in unchanging data

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I m using pyspark sql in azure data brick and while querying unchanging data I found number of rows while executing the query is different every time i run.
when I run 1st time it had 3389265 rows. 2nd time 3389365 and third time 3389284 rows. How can I get constant result instead this this result?

Here is my code:-

```
%sql
with sales_item as
(
  SELECT  column
      ,row_number()  over (partition by voucher_date,company,product_id,customer_id,sales_catalog_id,sdmcu order by voucher_date desc) as rn
      FROM  (SELECT  column
    FROM f42119_df
    WHEREsddgl >= now()::date - interval '24 months'
      and SDDCTO in ('SO','SR','SD','C1','C2','C3','C5','SH','SX','C4')
    UNION
    SELECT column
    FROM f5542119_df   WHERE
      sddgl >= now()::date - interval '24 months'   and SDDCTO in ('SO','SR','SD','C1','C2','C3','C5','SH','SX','C4'))

),f4101 AS (
SELECT colunmn ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IMITM ORDER BY IMUPMJ DESC) AS rn
FROM f4101_df 
),
f03012 as (
select column
    FROM(
    column
    ,row_number() over(partition by aian8,aico order by aiupmj DESC) as rb
from f03012_df
where btrim(aico) in ('00001','00003')
 order by aian8,aico
) as address
    where rb = 1
),
sales_base as(
 select 
     column
      ,case
          when substr(btrim(t4.SHURRF),1,1) in ('P','2','4','5','7','S') then 'Showroom'
          when substr(btrim(t4.SHURRF),1,1) in ('6') then 'Inside Sales'
          when (t1.reason_code) in ('A','B') or btrim(t4.SHTKBY) in ('EXP') then 'Express'
          when btrim(t4.SHIR01) in ('B2B', 'EDI', 'ICM', 'WBXML' ,'APP' ,'ICTWEB') then 'E-commerce'
          else 'Inside Sales'
          end as sales_channel
     from sales_item as t1
left join f4101 as t2 on t1.product_id_2=t2.product_id_2 and t2.rn=1
left join f03012 as t3 on 
  t1.customer_id=t3.aian8 and t1.company=t3.aico
left join f4201_df as t4
on t1.order_company= btrim(t4.SHKCOO) and t1.SDDOCO=t4.SHDOCO 
and t1.SDDCTO=btrim(t4.SHDCTO)
where t1.rn=1
),
sales as
(
  column
  from
(column
    ,row_number() over (partition by product_id_2,company,date_format(voucher_date, 'yyyy-MM'),customer_segment,customer_group ORDER BY date_format(voucher_date, 'yyyy-MM') desc) as rn
  from sales_base
) as a
where rn=1 and quantity <>0
ORDER BY voucher_date
)
select count(*) from sales
```

What's went run? How can I fix this issue.
Update:- Till table sales_base it's fine but in last table rows keep changing.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason why the number of rows is changing every time you run the query is likely due to the use of the **row_number()** function without specifying an order in the final sales table.
When you don't specify an order, the order in which the rows are returned can be changing.

To get a constant result, you can add an ORDER BY clause to the row_number() function in the final sales table.
You can order the rows by a column  that uniquely identify each row.

Try the blow way in your code
,row_number() over (partition by product_id_2,company,date_format(voucher_date, 'yyyy-MM'),customer_segment,customer_group ORDER BY voucher_date desc) as rn

Also you can try this approach
you are ordering the results by **voucher_date**. This may lead to variations in the output because it could be change based on how the data is processed.
You can try adding a secondary sort key, such as **product_id_2 or customer_segment**, to ensure consistent ordering of rows.
[image]
For example I have created a dataframe wih sample data
[image]

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import asc
sales_df = sales_df.orderBy(asc("product_id"))
sales_df.show()
```

[image]

You can use the **Rank()** and **DenseRank()** functions
I have applied it for the Sales dataframe.
from pyspark.sql.functions import rank, dense_rank

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
 - create a window specification
window_spec = Window.orderBy("voucher_date")
#use rank() function to rank sales by voucher date
sales_df = sales_df.withColumn("rank", rank().over(window_spec))
#use dense_rank() function to rank sales by voucher date
sales_df = sales_df.withColumn("dense_rank", dense_rank().over(window_spec))
show the DataFrame with ranks
sales_df.show()
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

rank and dense_rank, adds two new columns to the DataFrame which show the rank of each row based on the voucher_date column.
The rank function assigns a unique rank to each row, but if there are similar voucher dates  it skips the next rank number.
The dense_rank function  assigns a unique rank to each row, and if there are same records, it assigns the same rank to all tied rows.